# Wireless menu bar item doesn't show up

Tags: wireless, gnome, menu

Sometimes when I start my ubuntu system the wireless menu bar item doesn't show up. This makes it impossible for me to connect to a wireless network as I don't know where the wireless menu item is hidden in the GNOME menu tree

How do I get my wireless menu item back again without restarting the system and why does this happen?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using `nm-applet`.  This applet is notoriously buggy at times.  Just last month or so people were complaining about it either not showing up or having a duplicate wireless icon showing up.  I would look at the most recent bug reports on launchpad.  It works fine for me, but there might be some interaction with a Gnome panel or something that is causing this.

Comment: Forgot to mention this...Try `pgrep nm-applet` in the terminal.  If you get a number, e.g. 2433, that means it is running but not showing up in the system tray.  If you just get the prompt, then it's not running at all and you should try adding `nm-applet` to the startup apps, as someone suggests below.

Answer (score 1):

To get the Connection info applet to start if it doesn't on startup, press Alt+F2 and run `nm-applet`. I'm not too sure why it isn't starting up for you. I would recommend adding the command `nm-applet` to your startup commands. If this command doesn't work, let me know.

Also, to access the actual program without a bar menu item, run this in terminal: `nm-connection-editor`.

Edit: This is what I use to start the applet and program in Unity. I'm not too sure what it is in GNOME, but I assume it can't be too different. Also, I'm not sure if Alt+F2 works in GNOME, I've only used Unity. Alt+F2 runs a command.